# Is it right to add <a> tag inside <span> tag?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Can we have anchor tag inside span tag? (Specially in IE)

like,

```
<span> <a href="#">Something</a></span>
```

Comment: What happend when you try that ?

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: It's valid HTML. Whether it is "right" depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: The best answer to this question would probably be: Why not?

Comment: Both are inline elements and it isn't a disallowed combination as far as I know. But, why exactly the IE clarification?

Comment: Yeah, but i'm using data-editable so what is the best way to deal with it?

Comment: @Mallikarjuna Rao: Just... deal with it? You aren't making any sense. And you asked a completely different question without telling the whole story. Just spell out the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, its valid HTML but it really depends on what you're trying to do.

ie;

```
<span id="something"> <a href="#">Something</a></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input). If you try this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">   
<title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
<span> <a href="#">Something</a></span> 
</body>

</html>
```

You will see that there is no error nor warning.